# What is the correct way to initialize spring properties (profiles etc.) using java config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config, spring-profiles

I have a file named initParameters.properties which contains a key named spring.profiles.active that's being filtered but that's not enough, because Spring is not aware of this property yet.
I'm using **AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer** as my WebAppInitializer 
 and here is the important part of it:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
    setInitParameters(servletContext);
}

@SneakyThrows
private void setInitParameters(ServletContext servletContext) {
    Properties initParams = new Properties();
    initParams.load(new ClassPathResource("initParameters.properties").getInputStream());
    initParams.stringPropertyNames().stream().forEach(propertyName -> CHOOSE_OPTION_HERE);
}
```

**Option 1:**

```
servletContext.setInitParameter(propertyName, initParams.getProperty(propertyName))
```

**Option 2:**

```
System.setProperty(propertyName, initParams.getProperty(propertyName))
```

Both ways work, I just don't know what is the difference between them apart from one being a system property and the other an initParameter.
Ofc, when I set system property -Dspring.profiles.active=someProfile while starting an application, it overrides everything, even the filtering in my .properties file so it's all fine.
I was looking all over the internet for some explanations, pros/cons but couldn't find anything. 
 Also, if there's a way to notify spring about the property directly from .properties file, I'd also like to know how (aka skipping the setInitParameters part). I think Spring Boot automatically detects it but I'm NOT using it so was wondering if there's something like that in Spring. Thanks for your time.